# Action icons on context menu

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, guidelines, hci

I have an object and a menu on its toolbar. When user clicks this an menu icon from top toolbar, a context menu opens in drop down like shown below:

[image]

There can be actully three kinds of objects so I have divided the context menu in three groups.
Each of these objects can be deleted or edited.
To remove/delete an object/menu, user hovers on its name, a delete icon appears and clicking that icon will delete the object.

Now my concern is that if user wants to edit a menu how will I show edit icon against it? as delete icon is already appearing on hover.

What guideline should I follow to develop such sort of context menu? Already read Apple and Microsoft's guidelines for context menu but couldn't find any scenario like this.

I want to have something like this:

[image]

but I'm not sure how will this look on UI.

Comment: have you thought about touch devices that have no hover capabilities?

Comment: Princess, if you are not already aware - UX.SE has a wireframe tool built in. When you want a simple wireframe click the icon, just above the text entry, with the pencil on it - it is the 7th icon from the left. Quick way to draw a picture that helps get your point across.

Answer (score 2):

**Use sub menus with edit and delete options.**

It may not provide such immediate access to the options, but it would definitely fit the 'familiarity' aspect of how users expect to interact with menus.

Sub-menus mean the options have more room to breath and are easier to click on rather than tiny areas squeezed on to the end of the menu items.

It also allows you to provide more options easily at any time in the future without further cluttering the top level menu.

It would allow you to distance the delete option from the main menu so that it's harder to click accidentally - I suggest making it the bottom option in the sub-menu and separating it from any options above)

If you have *modes* where the options are available or not available then you can disable the sub-menu functionality as necessary.